# How to avoid being victim of Click Jacking?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, clickjacking

Is there a way to detect and avoid click jacking as a user other than using a different profile on Chrome just for social activities ?

A decently famous site 'atozmp3 .co .in' is using click jacking to get Facebook Likes. Is there a way we can find the sites and make a blacklist of sort ?

```
$('#clickjack-button-wrapper-5').css('opacity','100')
```

All I could do at the Facebook website was 'Report the Page'. I see few other pages which get likes this way. Is there a way to detect it and avoid being a victim ?

Comment: Or "likejacking" prevention extensions like this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zscaler-likejacking-preve/jlhdmlalflfmcdmfgccnkmkanhnlhpcp

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [this thread](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/how-can-i-prevent-clickjacking-attacks-on-facebook).